# Angular is stripping attributes from HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Edit 2**: The issue was in fact with the sanitizer stripping my tags. The solution was passing it through a simple function :

```
self.markTrusted = function (markup) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(markup);
};
```

This allows marks it as trusted to Angular and will leave in my attributes. This did not, however, fix my linking problem, but that is outside the scope of this question.

Edit: Think I may have found the problem. The second anchor is actually `<a name="someSection"></a>`. I think the sanitizer may be catching it and removing it. Is there any way to tell the sanitizer to let it through?

I am using Angular version 1.5

I am trying to implement anchor links in my site. I found several answers on here that indicated that the following code should work with Angular to link within my page:

```
<a href="#someSection" target="_self">Text</a>

<a id="someSection"></a>
```

I have that code being passed (embedded in the my other HTML and content) to the front end by my API as a string, and I am displaying it on page like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="content.markup"></div>
```

The problem is though that for some reason my anchor tag is being stripped so now I have

```
<a href="#someSection" target="_self">Text</a>

<a></a>
```

which obviously doesn't work. Can anyone give me any ideas as to why that second anchor tag would be getting stripped of its attributes?

Comment: It's an Angular tag

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the href to the anchor tag: a id="someSection" href="#" /a
or if you do not want it to be clickable, use a span or p tag instead.